# app will not build for IOS - [VERBOSE0:callback_cache.cc(133)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, flutter-ios

i have been having this problem for 2 days now and can't seem to solve it, honestly have no idea what's causing it the app compiles but doesn’t start up, any ideas to solve it ?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              6.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        19.2s
Xcode build done.                                           129.2s
[VERBOSE0:callback_cache.cc(133)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore
```

Comment: flutter clean  command run on  terminal

Comment: and again  Build  create

Comment: i'm sorry what is build create ?

Comment: check my  answer

Answer (score -1):

Step  1:  `flutter clean`
Step  2:  this command use  `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/flutter/bin"`
Step  3:  `flutter build`

Comment: Please only use code formatting for code. If you need help editing, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.